# Send one subdomain to subdirectory, everything else to file with parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hoo-boy I've been struggling with this one all day.

The redirect from the subdomains to the script files with subdomain passed in as a parameter work fine.

When one particular subdomain is actually a real folder (phpmyadmin), I can't seem to make it work, at least not with the previously mentioned rule in place.

Here's my stuff:

```
<VirtualHost *.domain.com:443>
ServerName *.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
DocumentRoot /home/domain/web
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(phpmyadmin)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /phpmyadmin [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^\/script2$ /public/script2.php?param1=%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/script1.php?param1=%1 [L]
<Directory /home/domain/web>
Options -Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/domain/crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/domain/key
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(phpmyadmin)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /phpmyadmin [L]
```

1. In your target redirect, you do not change the domain. By just using /phpmyadmin, you're not directing to **www.domain.com/phpmyadmin**, you're directing to **phpmyadmin.domain.com/phpmyadmin**, which is likely to cause an infinite redirect loop since it will keep matching the phpmyadmin subdomain each redirect. Use:

   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/phpmyadmin [L]`
2. Unlike `RewriteRule` where the initial / is not used, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` does need the leading slash like so:

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin`

Failing to do so means its not matching the directed /phpmyadmin, leading to another potential self-matching infinite redirect loop.

Also you don't need

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]`

since your url would never start with www and also start with phpmyadmin. Matching

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(phpmyadmin)\.domain\.com`

automatically implies the NOT www match condition is also true

Comment: also without [R] flag, the redirect rule will act as an alias, meaning that phpmyadmin.domain.com is silently redirecting to www.domain.com/phpmyadmin behind the scenes but your url doesn't change. Replace [L] with [R=301,L] if you actually want to see the url change in the browser (atleast use for testing since its alot easier when you can see where the redirect goes)